# Using the Jira4R ruby gem, why can I update some custom field values and standard field values but not all?

Tags: field, jira, status

For issues created in Jira, I cannot seem to update either Status or Resolution in my Ruby code.  I also have several custom fields, most of which I can update, but there is one I cannot.  I have looked through the RubyGems documentation and Atlassian's documentation, as well as lots of other forums and blogs to no avail.  Could it have something to do with them being in separate workflows from the fields I can update?

Here is how I am attemting to update a particular ticket's fields (jira is my connection):

```
ticket = jira.getIssue('123')

person=Jira4R::V2::RemoteFieldValue.new("customfield_678", "smithj")

jira.updateIssue(ticket.key, person)
```

Again this works for some custom and some standard fields.  I do not get an error.  The ticket just comes back as if I have updated the field but it still has to old value.  Has anyone encountered this and what is my solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status or resolution needs to be done using:
jira.progressWorkflowAction( ticket.key, status.id, [remote field array])  where status.id = the id of the new resolution you want to transition to.